# Why was this question moved to Programmers.SE?

Tags: discussion, migration, software-engineering-se

I see [Euler cycle finding question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126871/euler-cycle-finding-algorithm) is moved to Programmers, I don't know Programmers rules, but as I can see this question is a really algorithmic question and fits SO rules, maybe it's a homework, but I can't see why it shouldn't be in SO? If it's better fit in Programmers (I don't know what's the Programmers usage), it doesn't mean it shouldn't be in SO, it can be an offered as a comment to ask this in Programmers, not moving.

**Edit:** To be clear, the question asked there is not my question, and also as you can see OPs name is user324u2348823493824 . I don't know him, but I think this migration was not good, it can be a comment.

Comment: I don't know why this question gets downvote?!! I'll be very happy to know that.

Comment: Votes on meta indicate agreement/disagreement with whatever is being asked/proposed/premise of the discusion, etc.

Comment: read about voting at meta here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences **"Please don't be concerned if you receive downvotes – members of the community may simply disagree..."**

Comment: and when they disagreed that means less rep for you :o * *facepalm* *

Comment: @VictorT. who care about rep :) but it's better to describe their disagreement.

Answer (score 8):

The very first bullet point on the [Programmers FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) is:

> - algorithm and data structure **concepts**

<sub>emphasis mine</sub>

So it fits there. Stack Overflow is more geared towards algorithm *implementation* rather than the theoretical/whiteboard aspect of it. Since the question didn't specify an implementation language, or any information about the technical data structures the asker is using, I guess it was judged too "theoretical" for Stack Overflow, but on target for Programmers.

Note that question was migrated by a moderator, one that happens to be a moderator on both of those sites - they usually have a very good idea about what should go where, especially when the moderate both sides of the migration.

Comment: First of all that's not my question, It's question for another user and I just like to answer it in SO not in other sites, by personal reason (e.g I don't like programmers UI, competitor, ...) So I prefer to think on it if it's on SO, Also I mean yes may be programmer is better place for that, but it doesn't mean SO is not good place, SO related to programming concepts, Also algorithm is related too, so It's good for SO, and yes, as I can see moderator do this, he/she can offer to do this to the OP, not doing himself, Also I like to know moderator reason.

Comment: In fact I think it's kind of dictatorship, without helping the people, may be OP heard that SO good from his/her classmates/co-workers, ... but moving this to the other site, means: OP you don't know ask what where, we decide for you, as you can see OP left the programmer totally.

Comment: I didn't realize it wasn't your question, sorry about that. But it doesn't change what I said about it. In my opinion, and I assume in the opinion of that moderator (who possibly reacted to migration request flags), it is a better fit for Programmers. If you like this type of question, and want to answer it, you should spend more time over at that site - the UI is really a minor thing. The OP didn't "leave" programmers. It appears he isn't registered there (yet), that's all. Note that the OP was also pretty new to SO. Helping him find the right site to post on is a good thing.

Comment: (and for the UI part, there are I believe userscript-type plugins you can use to tweak it) (and be careful who you call "dictators" - that's insulting to the whole community)

Comment: If you aren't the person moved the question it's better to say "in my opinion" not guessing moderator opinion, Also is obvious that I can guess what was the reason of moderator (as I mentioned in my question), but as I said, this doesn't cause to move it, If is so, I can flag too many question (at least 50% of questions in SO+Algorithm tag) should be migrated, but this causes to low quality of SO and I never do so.

Comment: Also if I call someone treated like dictator, I don't think I mean community, Also I think community can go in this way (dictatorship) if they continue this way (In all saying this is not bad, but don't saying this is bad it will be like our country :).

Comment: As a moderator on Programmers, if I'd seen this I would have migrated it too.

Comment: @Saeed Mat's post pretty much sums it up. You're welcome to disagree with the scope of various SE sites and you don't have to join different sites if you don't want to, but that doesn't mean that migrations from/to those sites should not or will not happen.